# Computer connects to the wrong router

Tags: router, dns, dhcp

I have 2 routers connected together and multiple computers connected to each router. (see image)

The problem is that when I connect a computer to Router 1 and let it get the IP automatically, it connects to the Router 2 (default gateway, DHCP and DNS are set to 192.168.1.117).

So for every computer that uses my network I need to set IP, default gateway and DNS server addresses manually. I would like to get IPs and all setting set automatically. If I disconnect Router 2 everything works ok. Router 1 is Linksys WRT54G and Router 2 is TP-LINK TL-WR741N.

[image]

Comment: Router brands? Models? How is you DHCPO configured? Can you dump the configs?

Comment: Which of the two routers provides DHCP? (and I hope the answer is not 'both').

Comment: DHCP is enabled on both routers. The guy who installed them did so. He said the computers were fighting over IP addresses. He set IP range on Router 2 from 192.168.1.150 to 192.168.1.199. I guess I should disable DHCP on Router 2 and se how it works.

Comment: Are you able to access the configuration for the routers? Set one of them to be a DHCP server and the other to be a DHCP relay.

Comment: This setup, using the same subnet (192.168.1.X) everywhere looks just wrong. What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you need one router and one switch, not two routers.

Comment: Unfortunately these routers have just on or off option for dhcp (plus start and end address and dns addresses). Router 2 is placed about 80-100 meters from Router 1 and it's used to provide wireless access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both routers are on the same subnet (192.168.1.0/24) and since router 2 is not performing any actual routing tasks you can just use it as a simple Wireless Access Point or as a simple switch.

Disable DHCP on it.

Any device connected to router 2 (regardless if it is via wired or via wireless) will be part of the same subnet and its broadcasts will be echoed across all of the subnet. Including to router 1. Router 1 can then answer all DHCP requests for the whole network.